# Get next available date (first date which doesn't exist in mysql taken_dates table)

Tags: mysql

I am looking to create a query to get the next date ( after today) which doesn't exist in a table.

In that table, I save all the dates which are taken. It can be random. So I need the very next date which is not yet saved in this table.

Theoretically, I was thinking if I can get the difference between every 2 subsequent dates from that table that should give me a clue about which have blank date ranges available. Not really sure how do I code this out.

I am avoiding using PHP here and want to do it all in MySQL

```
Table(booked_dates)
user_id (int)
booked_date (date)

so if this table say contains entries like below.
2, 2018-07-08,
2, 2018-07-09
2, 2018-07-10
2, 2018-07-11
2, 2018-07-12
2, 2018-07-15
2, 2018-07-17
```

And I run the said query on `'2018-07-09'` then expect to get `2017-07-13` as the output of the query.

Comment: Removed it mate @Epodax. No Need to downvote. Still editing the question.

Comment: Provide table structures, example data place it on sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com. And create ascii data table (text formatted) with expected results based on the example data.. For now i voteclose this question to be unclear clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You should post your question when it's complete, not half finished.

Comment: Generate table with all possible dates. Join with that table, but specify right condition. Profit.

Comment: how many dates in advantage should the query be able to look?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I want to avoid putting any constraint on how long in the future that date could be. It could be the next year. There's isn't a constraint as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(booked_date date NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2018-07-08'),
('2018-07-09'),
('2018-07-10'),
('2018-07-11'),
('2018-07-12'),
('2018-07-15'),
('2018-07-17');

SELECT MIN(x.booked_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY) dt 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.booked_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY = x.booked_date 
 WHERE y.booked_date IS NULL;
+------------+
| dt         |
+------------+
| 2018-07-13 |
+------------+
```

Comment: That's it. That's what I was thinking of doing but was unable to code it down.

Comment: "And I run the said query on '2018-07-09' then expect to get 2017-07-13 as the output of the query." The `WHERE` should be `WHERE x.booked_date > CURRENT_DATE() AND y.booked_date IS NULL` @Ankit if you want to make the query output depended of the day where the query runs on

Answer (score 1):

This will return a list of openings, along with the first open date in each.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a48ee7/7)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `booked_dates`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `booked_dates` (
    `id`            INT(11) UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT          COMMENT 'Primary Key',
    `user_id`       INT(11) UNSIGNED        NULL        DEFAULT NULL            COMMENT 'User ID - FK to users',
    `booked_date`   DATE                    NULL        DEFAULT '0000-00-00'    COMMENT 'Date Booked',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `idx_booked_date` (`booked_date`),
    KEY `idx_user_id` (`user_id`)
) 
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    COMMENT '';

INSERT INTO `booked_dates`
(`user_id`,`booked_date`)
VALUES
(2, '2018-07-08'),
(2, '2018-07-09'),
(2, '2018-07-10'),
(2, '2018-07-11'),
(2, '2018-07-12'),
(2, '2018-07-15'),
(2, '2018-07-17');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  a.`booked_date`,
  a.`booked_date` as `d1`,
  b.`booked_date` as `d2`,
  DATE_ADD(a.`booked_date`,INTERVAL 1 DAY) as `First Available`,
  DATEDIFF(b.`booked_date`,a.`booked_date`) as `date diff`
FROM `booked_dates` a
JOIN `booked_dates` b
ON a.`booked_date` < b.`booked_date`
GROUP BY a.`booked_date`
HAVING `date diff` > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a48ee7/7/0)**:

```
| booked_date |         d1 |         d2 | First Available | date diff |
|-------------|------------|------------|-----------------|-----------|
|  2018-07-12 | 2018-07-12 | 2018-07-15 |      2018-07-13 |         3 |
|  2018-07-15 | 2018-07-15 | 2018-07-17 |      2018-07-16 |         2 |
```

Comment: 'Better late than never' ;-)

Comment: LOL, At least it's a slightly different approach. @Strawberry, nice solution too.